# VSCode cross-origin request inside WebView

Tags: visual-studio-code, cors, vscode-extensions

I'm working on extension which based on VSCode [WebView](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). Extension make integration with issue tracking system over HTTP API, like Jira. I want to render information about issue in WebView and create some forms for making comments and changing issue status. I don't want to use message passing between extension and WebView. When I try to create HTTP request to API inside WebView I got error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Server does't support Access-Control-Allow-Origin for "null" or "localhost" Origin.

Is the way to create HTTP request from WebView to server ignoring missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? Maybe I can setup some policy for WebView panel? Or create localhost proxy inside extension and make request over proxy?

Code example

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    vscode.commands.registerCommand('catCoding.start', () => {
      // Create and show panel
      const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
        'catCoding',
        'Cat Coding',
        vscode.ViewColumn.One,
        {enableScripts: true}
      );

      // And set its HTML content
      panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
    })
}

function getWebviewContent() {
  return `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cat Coding</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://google.com', true);
        xhr.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>`;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/72900)

> There is no vscode support for changing this. You should think of the webview more as an html view (one that does not have any server or origin) rather than a webpage
>
> Posters on stackoverflow may have suggestions for workarounds

Answer (score 1):

Support for Cross Origin Isolation was just added for Webview through the use of the `vscode-coi` url parameter; see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137884